# Could not find implicit value for parameter in scala

Tags: scala, implicit

```
    def p1(c: Int)(implicit b: Int): Unit = {
        println(c + b)
    }

    def p2(a: Int, b: Int): Unit ={
        p1(a)
    }

    p2(5, 6) //result = 11
```

> **error: could not find implicit value for parameter b: Int**

how to fix problem but dont use this solution

```
 def p2(a: Int, b: Int): Unit ={
        implicit val bb = b
        p1(a)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

#### One way is to Explicitly passing `b`

```
def p2(a: Int, b: Int): Unit ={
    p1(a)(b)
}
```

#### Second way is to Mark `b` as implicit in the signature of `p2`

```
def p2(a: Int)(implicit b: Int): Unit ={
  p1(a)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, but i want to use p1 with only a parameter "a": p1(a).
your second answer failed at compilation.

Comment: @TrầnTúNam there is no way to do that. other than `implicit` in scope.